# elasticsearch pagination with sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I got pagination on items with an order by price, there are a lot of items with price 0, and I think because of that I can't get items after receiving the first item with zero price.

here is simplified query

```
sort: [ { price: 'desc' }, { _id: 'asc' } ],
search_after: [ 0, 'indexName#_previousDocId' ]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: are you using this configuration? It seems that you sort on _id field and search_after on _uid

Comment: yes, I get _id from last doc I received and put it into `indexName#{HERE}`

Comment: so in your index all the values of _id field begin with indexName# ?

Comment: No it is name of index, actualy I think it is from old version of elastic, because without `indexName#` seem like work well

Comment: You should not use `_id` as a tie breaker id directly, rather you should create a copy of it with doc values enabled. Please see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the case here is that I misused `indexName#_previousDocId`, there should be no type, so just `_previousDocId`